# List appending in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, append, list-comprehension

So I wrote a function that takes a list of lists as an argument and takes every single element from the first list and appends it to a recursively called function on the list of lists' tail, in result returning all possible combinations of selecting elements from these lists.

```
foo :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
foo [] = [[]]
foo (x:xs) = [[(x !! a)] ++ b | a <- [0..length(x)-1], b <- foo xs]

*Main> foo [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

It indeed works how it should, but whenever I change the second line of my function to

```
foo [] = []
```

it always returns an empty list whenever I call it on a type-valid argument. What's the big deal?

Comment: with the changes your `b <- foo xs` will not be able to get *anything* when `xs` get's empty (because *pull a `b` from nothing* will never get a `b`)- this is the **big deal** (in the right case it will pull `b <- [[]]` so `b` will get `[]`) :D

Comment: is this ok as an answer for you?

Comment: Yep, I totally understand this now.

Comment: can you explain a bit more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with `foo [] = []` the very last `b <- foo xs` will not be able to get anything when `xs == []`, because it wants to pull a `b` from nothing - so the list-comprehension will be empty.

with the `foo [] = [[]]` it will finally be `b <- [[]]` so `b` will get a single [].

### remark

you can simplify this a bit (so you don't need the costly `(!!)`):

```
foo :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
foo [] = [[]]
foo (xs:xss) = [ y : ys | y <- xs, ys <- foo xss]
```

I think this is easier to read/explain too: take every `x` from `xs` and recursively combine it with every combination of the `xss` into a new list

### what would go wrong with `foo [] = []`:

Let's test it with a simple case:

```
foo [[1],[2]]
= [ y:ys | y  <- [1], ys <- foo [ [2] ] ]
= [ 1:ys | ys <- [ y':ys' | y' <- [2], ys' <- foo [] ] ]
= [ 1:ys | ys <- [ 2:ys'  | ys' <- [] ] ]
= [ 1:ys | ys <- [] ]
= []
```

instead of (with `foo [] = [[]]`):

```
foo [[1],[2]]
= [ y:ys | y  <- [1], ys <- foo [ [2] ] ]
= [ 1:ys | ys <- [ y':ys' | y' <- [2], ys' <- foo [] ] ]
= [ 1:ys | ys <- [ 2:ys'  | ys' <- [[]] ] ]
= [ 1:ys | ys <- [ 2:[] ] ]
= [ 1:[2] ]
= [ [1,2] ]
```